# Centering a dynamic string in Rust?

Tags: rust, formatting

```
fn main() {
    println!("{:=^50}", "Stuff");
    println!("{:=^50}", format_args!("Stuff {}", 42));
}
```

One would think there's no reason it shouldn't work, but actually, it doesn't:

```
======================Stuff=======================
Stuff 42
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7797aab7fc5c424a2fc16516488a501b).

I can just do it myself, sure, but is there a built in way to do this?

Comment: I'm... surprised you can even pass `Arguments` to `println!` directly. I mean, I guess it makes sense, but it seems kind of magical.

Comment: But it's not, [`std::io::_print`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/770b9e3012bd58bdf6046d328dabfd57df163eb6/src/libstd/io/stdio.rs#L801), which is called by `print!` and `println!` macros directly accepts `Arguments`... Hence the confusion.

Comment: But `println!` *itself* calls `format_args!` on its arguments, so you're making an `Arguments` that *contains* an `Arguments`. The reason it works is because [`Arguments` itself implements `Display`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/struct.Arguments.html), which is the part that surprises me.

Comment: Yes, I tried to do it this way because I'm aware of it, you can chain `format_args!` as many times as possible and that's something I gotten used to doing to allocate as little as possible for logging... And it always worked for most things, just for some reason alignment is special in some way and also is completely ignored. When I noticed, I doublechecked my code just to check whether I did something wrong, because it does work for pretty much everything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fbdd906f301ea82753ff3e88f7ccd505) (see [fmt](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/index.html)):

```
fn main() {
    println!("{:=^50}", "Stuff");
    println!("{:=^50}", format!("Stuff {}", 42));
}
```

Output:

```
======================Stuff=======================
=====================Stuff 42=====================
```

---

Try [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=cf435d5ce59ee7260ce692cc60fe616c):

```
fn main() {
    println!("{:=^50}", "Stuff");
    println!("{:=^50}", std::fmt::format(format_args!("Stuff {}", 42)));
}
```

Output:

```
======================Stuff=======================
=====================Stuff 42=====================
```

---

See [format_args](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.format_args.html):

> This macro produces a value of type fmt::Arguments. This value can be passed to the macros within std::fmt for performing useful redirection. All other formatting macros (format!, write!, println!, etc) are proxied through this one. format_args!, unlike its derived macros, avoids heap allocations.

[Arguments](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/struct.Arguments.html):

> The format_args! macro will safely create an instance of this structure. The macro validates the format string at compile-time so usage of the write and format functions can be safely performed.

See [Display for Arguments](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/fmt/mod.rs.html#415-419):

```
impl Display for Arguments<'_> {
    fn fmt(&self, fmt: &mut Formatter<'_>) -> Result {
        write(fmt.buf, *self)
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be nice to explain why the extra allocation is necessary.

Comment: That still doesn't really explain why `format_args!` arguments don't respect the width parameter, which I'm assuming is because they can't predict the actual width of what they are going to display, unlike `format!` which knows because it uses a temporary buffer.

Comment: Exactly, I'm not following. [`std::io::_print`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/770b9e3012bd58bdf6046d328dabfd57df163eb6/src/libstd/io/stdio.rs#L801), which is called by `print!` and `println!` macros directly accepts `Arguments`... Did I just find a bug? It shouldn't silently fail. Other than that, I asked if there's a way to do it, and I got an answer, thanks.

Comment: Since `format_args!`  produces a value of type `fmt::Arguments` and `std::fmt::Display`  trait of `fmt::Arguments` has no alignment (look inside [source code](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/fmt/mod.rs.html#415-419))